# Выдержки меток не видны, если новая версия находится в ожидании проверки

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, метки

## Ошибка

После правки краткие описания меток пусты. Должна быть новая версия или хотя бы старая, шаблонная. Все остальные пользователи и анонимы тоже не видят ни одну из версий. Скриншот сделан в анонимном режиме Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С точки зрения анонимного пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему нет выдержки? Была же только что!

## Воспроизведение

Изменил краткие описания (выдержки) для следующих меток:

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), 
[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced).

В данный момент правки находятся в ожидании проверки.

У `norepro` уже был текст на русском, у остальных — только на английском. Полагаю, что эти метки и описания к ним являются частью шаблона сайта StackExchange и у них нет первой версии текста правки (а вместо него используется какая-то заглушка, которая слетает при вышеописанных действиях).

Вот для сравнения истории двух описаний (новых правок в истории еще нет):

[image: status-deferred]

[image: status-norepro]

Comment: из перечисленных меток сейчас вижу описание только у `norepro`. для остальных описаний не отображается.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да, и у VlaD так же, и у незарегистрированных пользьвателей. Описание-заглушка просто пропадает.

Comment: Если вдруг такая печаль везде, лучше запостить на Meta.SE, ибо это значит, что баг в движке.

Comment: @Vesper: я думал, что сотрудники конкретных сайтов могут сразу проверить и зарепортить баг в какой-нибудь внутренний трекер. Но уже почти сутки ответа нет, пойду сам писать на мету.